# I trying to unit test my work, somehow waitfor isn't working? It's timing out

Tags: reactjs

I have a unit test, I've already mocked my `fetchAppList` and `fetchTotalAppCount` but somehow when I try to render my component, but I keep getting this error:

```
  ● loads the correct number of apps

    Timed out in waitFor.

      11 |     render(<IntegrationsPage/>);
      12 |
    > 13 |     const appList = await waitFor(() => screen.findAllByText("Notify me when it's ready"));
         |                                  ^
      14 |     expect(appList).toHaveLength(10);
      15 | });

      at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:187:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/integrations/IntegrationsPage.test.js:13:34)
```

This is what my test looks like:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import IntegrationsPage from "./IntegrationsPage";
import apps from "../../api/apps/Apps";
import mockData from "../../api/apps/MockData";

jest.mock("../../api/apps/Apps");

test("loads the correct number of apps", async() => {
    apps.fetchAppList.mockResolvedValue(mockData);
    apps.fetchTotalAppCount.mockImplementation(() => mockData.length);
    render(<IntegrationsPage/>);

    const appList = await waitFor(() => screen.findAllByText("Notify me when it's ready"));
    expect(appList).toHaveLength(10);
});
```

The `integrationsPage` is using `useEffect` to render a list of apps. Each app has a link that says `Notify me when it's ready` in another child component.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const totalAppCount = Apps.fetchTotalAppCount()
        const pageCount = calculatePageCount(totalAppCount);

        Apps
        .fetchAppList(INITIAL_OFFSET,ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
        .then((result) => {
            setCurrentPage(INITIAL_PAGE);
            setTotalAppCount(totalAppCount);
            setPageCount(pageCount);
            setAppList(result);
        });

    },[]);
```

Comment: Have you tried a longer timeout? The default is 1000ms, but you can pass `{timeout:5000}` (for example) as a second argument to `waitFor`. And does it behave the same way if your expect is inside the `waitFor` callback? (It's been a long time since I've done frontend, but I seem to recall a limitation like that with expectation types at one point.)

Comment: I tried and it just gave me thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test."

Comment: If you set it to a ridiculously long timeout, like 30 seconds, does it ever resolve? If not — are you sure the mocked resolved value is correct? You could double-check with `const { debug } = render(<IntegrationsPage/>); debug();`